# Failed to upload image with puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to upload image with puppeteer, here's the code.

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core';
import express from 'express';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://localhost/test.php', {waitUntil:'networkidle0'});

const filePath = 'test.jpeg';
await page.waitForSelector('input[type=file]');
const inputElement = await page.$('input[type=file]');
await inputElement.uploadFile(filePath);

await page.waitForSelector('input[type=submit]');
const submitButton = await page.$('input[type=submit]');
await submitButton.click();

await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

const url = await page.url();
console.log(url)

if(url.startsWith('http')) {
    const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const body = document.querySelector('body');
        return body.textContent;
    });
    console.log(text);
}
```

This code works if I run in MacOS

But if I change to

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser', headless: 'new', args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']});
```

and run on Ubuntu. When the form send, It will redirect to `chrome-error://chromewebdata/` .

I had confirm that the image path and the upload page are right.